# How to save the complex values of a sine wave to a .txt file in GNU Radio?

Tags: python, file, save, gnu, txt

I am trying to save the complex values of a sine wave to a ".txt" file, using GNU Radio.
I have tried using the following diagram:

[image: Sine wave to .txt]

The values saved into the .txt file are either not readable or corrupted. Why is this happening?
Is there another way to limit the amount of data saved into the .txt file? As of now I am using the "head" block to do so.

This is what I see when I try to open the file:

[image: .txt file]